# Anyone knows and good guide for using Localization for Tornado?

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, tornado

I'm thoroughly reading Tornado Documentation and trying to learn Tornado.

But some parts need to be changed such as

```
{{ xsrf_form_html() }}
```

to

```
{% raw xsrf_form_html() %}
```

in [Cross-site request forgery protection](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection)

I have found that solution in wiki.

But I could not make example work for [Localization](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#localization)

It does not translate anything.

Anyone knows and good guide for using Localization for Tornado?

Comment: Please don't shout :) Put the question in the question title instead, where it'll be noticed.

Comment: Can you post a full example that does not work (possibly also with the client request -- locale uses some request handlers to work out the translation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try reading http://tornado-babel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html where the localisation process is explained. Though most of the content is relevant for the standard `tornado.locale` module, `tornado-babel` extends the functionality and uses babel for l10n and i18n.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call the `load_translations` method? Your app need to call that before `start_server`, e.g:

```
tornado.locale.load_translations(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "translations"))
```

You also need CSV files with your translations, [in the correct format.](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/locale.html#tornado.locale.load_translations)

Answer (score 1):

Working link to [tornado locale documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locale.html). But to my mind the i18n process is described quite poorly there.

Check out [this article](http://www.lexev.org/en/2015/tornado-internationalization-and-localization/), it explain the i18n and i10n processes in tornado with details and examples.